# Ionic 2 Issue on accessing values through different scope levels

Tags: angular, ionic2, cordova-nativestorage

I have create a new project with one page "home" and one provider "StorageService". I have difficulty in accessing the values through different scopes.

**StorageService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NativeStorage } from 'ionic-native';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class StorageService {
    private platform: Platform;
    public ip: string;
    public port: string;
    public constructor(platform: Platform) {
        this.platform = platform;
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            NativeStorage.getItem('connectionStorage')
                .then(
                data => {
                    this.ip = data.ip;
                    console.log("INSIDE CONSTRUCTOR1:" + this.ip);
                    // this.ip having the value here
                },
                error => {
                    console.log("STORAGE NOT FOUND");
                }
                );
            console.log("INSIDE CONSTRUCTOR2:" + this.ip);
            // this.ip having no value here
        });
        console.log("INSIDE CONSTRUCTOR3:" + this.ip);
            // this.ip having no value here
    }

    getIP(): string {

        console.log("INSIDE IP2:" + this.ip);
            // this.ip having no value here
        return this.ip;
    }

    createConnectionInfo(ip: string, port: string) {
        NativeStorage.setItem('connectionStorage', { ip: ip, port: port })
            .then(
            () => console.log('Stored Connection Information!'),
            error => console.error('Error storing connection information', error)
            );
    }
}
```

**Home.Component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StorageService } from '../services/storage.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [StorageService]
})
export class HomePage {

  service: StorageService;
  ip:string;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, service: StorageService) {
    this.service = service;
    this.ip = this.service.getIP();
    console.log("INSIDE HOME CONSTRUCTOR : "+this.ip);
  }

  setStorage() {
    this.service.createConnectionInfo("192.168.1.1", "80");
  }

}
```

This is what i get on the console when i run this program:

```
ionic $ 6     442472   log      Stored Connection Information!                                                                  
0     452556   log      INSIDE CONSTRUCTOR3:undefined                                                                           
1     452559   log      INSIDE IP2:undefined                                                                                    
2     452562   log      INSIDE HOME CONSTRUCTOR : undefined                                                                     
3     452727   log      DEVICE READY FIRED AFTER, 225, ms                                                                       
4     452757   log      INSIDE CONSTRUCTOR2:undefined                                                                           
5     452815   log      INSIDE CONSTRUCTOR1:192.168.1.1
```

I assigned the value of this.ip inside the nativestorage get function but couldn't access it from outside. I know i'm doing something wrong but couldn't find what. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You are trying to access async (from Promise) value synchronously. Try using `EventEmitter` or `Subject` (explained here: [Parent and children communicate via a service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service).)

Comment: Thanks @Sasxa for the reply. but still couldn't figure out how to implement subjects in ionic 2. Could you please send me a simple program?